# ASP.net ListView with groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I can't seem to find a good answer for this.  I'm trying to set up a webpage to grab data from a database and display it something like:

**username1**
   image1.jpg
   imagename

image2.jpg
   imagename2

**username2**
   image3.jpg
   imagename3

**username3**
   image4.jpg
   imagename4

image5.jpg
   imagename5

image6.jpg
   imagename6

There is a username, and with that username there is one or more images and image names.  Not all the usernames will have the same number of images.

My question is, what is the best way to do this?  I am able to accomplish this using a repeater control with a nested repeater.  It's messy but works.

From what I've read, a ListView should be able to do the same thing but much cleaner.  My problem with a ListView is that I have to set the GroupItemCount, it's not dynamic like i need.  I think I can nest another ListView, but it turns out to be as much code as using a repeater.

Is one of these methods (repeater or listview) preferred over the other. Or is there a better way to do this that i'm not thinking of?  I don't think that what i'm trying to do is out of the ordinary, so I think there would be a quicker way.  To me, it seems much easier to do this in classic asp using for loops.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

The GroupTemplate is instantiated when a certain number (GroupItemCount) of ItemTemplate are instantiated. The ItemTemplate is called for each object in the collection and you first have a collection of users. Even if you can change the GroupItemCount during the ItemDataBound event, this will reflect how the next group of users is created. There is nothing about images until now, so I can say that you can't use ListView for a such task.

Using a repeater inside the ItemTemplate of the main Repeater (or ListView if you want) is the best choice, also common, so you don't have to worry about the mess, another developer will easily see your intention.